# Generate (i.e. write) a row number index column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need a row number index in my MySQL tables, based on ORDERing on a table column. I know about the

```
SELECT ... @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number ...
```

trick which will output the row number; what I actually want, however, is for that row number to be *written into the table* as a persistent column. Performance is a critical issue. What is the best way of accomplishing this?

Comment: when you say 'written into the table' do you mean 'written into the table every time a row is inserted'? Or do you have a table that just needs a one off update to set the new persistent column?

Comment: Ideally, I'd have both: First I need to update the table by inserting the column for all existing rows, from that point on I want it to be automatically inserted when I add new rows.

Comment: How big is the table? Performance is going to be a stumbling block here since each time a new row is inserted whatever process decides what the rank of the new column is going to be will have to assess *all* rows in the table each time a new row is inserted. Why do you need this persistent column?

Comment: I need the column to quickly access previous/next records based on a record. The table currently has about 9 million rows.

Comment: That is very hard to maintain. What if row 4567899 (...or some row in the middle of the table) is deleted? Then what? You will renumber every single row after that row decrementing the *row_number* field? I don't think that this is possible unless you do not care about performance. The nearest to that is an INT field with the AUTO_INCREMENT property, but it must be part of the PRIMARY KEY as well (but it is still not achieving exactly what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tip from a friend saved the day. This seems to be the fastest way to accomplish the task:

1. Create a new table with identical column structure as the original one with the addition of an auto-increment column.
2. Add the data from the original table to the new one using INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ORDER BY
3. Delete the original table

Did 9 million rows in 7 seconds.