# Filter out orphan table entries

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates, gaps-and-islands

Suppose there is a table with only two columns (an example is shown below). Every '1' entry should be followed (in the sorted order given below) by a '0'. However, as you can see, in the table, there are some 'orphans' where there are two consecutive '1's.

How can I create a query that returns all the rows, except for the first of any consecutive '1's? (This would reduce the example below from 16 rows to 14)

```
1 E
0 A
1 T
0 S
1 R
0 E
1 F
0 T
1 G
1 T
0 R
1 X
1 R
0 R
1 E
0 T
```

---

I'm going to try and clarify my problem, I think that above I simplified it too much. Imagine one table called `logs`, with four columns:

- `user` (a string containing a username)
- `machine` (a string uniquely identifying various PCs)
- `type` (event's type: a 1 for log**i**n and a 0 for log**o**ut)
- `time` (the time of the event being logged)

[The machine/time pair provides a unique key, as no machine can be logged in or out of twice at the same instant. Presumably an 'ID' column could be artificially created based on machine/time sort if needed.]

The idea is that every login event should be accompanied by a logout event. In an ideal word it would be fairly easy to match logins to logouts, and hence analyse the time spent logged in.

However, in the case of a power cut, the logout will not be recorded. Therefore (considering only one machine's data, sorted by time) if there are two login events in a row, we want to ignore the first login, because we don't have any reliable data from it.  This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: SQL tables have no order. Wanting a row being followed by another row has no sense. If you want a natural order **use an id**.

Comment: How is the ordering achieved? We can assume an additional id column for that?

Comment: @Erwin, Yes there are some other columns (that provide the sort order) that I am ignoring (because I thought that would make things more simple, and focus on the problem)

Comment: @fluteflute, since the ID is essential in determining the 'next' record in the sequence, it is an essential part of the problem. Benoit has posted a solution that relies on IDs being an unbroken sequence of numbers iterated by 1 - is this realistic?

Comment: Also, table and column names would help.

Comment: @MarkBannister I've updated my post with table and column names

Comment: My assumptions match your edit. There can never be two consecutive 0's (but if there were, I would filter the first ones). And there *can* be more than two consecutive 1's, and you want to get rid of *all* of them except the last one, followed by 0. But you need a row_number (id in the example) that can be counted up and down for this type of query to work.

Answer (score 1):

Provided, that

- only 1's are dupes, never 0's
- You want to get rid of *all* the first 1's if there are more.

Your text says "except for the first of any consecutive", but I think, this is what you want. Or there can only ever be 2, then it is the same.

```
SELECT x.*
FROM   x
LEFT   JOIN x y on y.id = (x.id + 1)
WHERE  (x.nr = y.nr) IS NOT TRUE -- OR x.nr = 0
ORDER  BY x.id
```

If you want to preserve double 0's, use the commented clause additionally, but probably not needed.

#### Edit after question edit:

You may want to add an auto-increment column to your data to make this simpler:
[Generate (i.e. write) a row number index column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675120/generate-i-e-write-a-row-number-index-column-in-mysql/7711379#7711379)

Other RDBMS (PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ..) have window functions like `row_number()` or `lag()` and `lead()` that make such an operation much easier.

Comment: The commented clause appears to be needed, otherwise the last item in the table (a '0' is removed)

Comment: @fluteflute: there must be an error of some kind. `y.nr` for the "last" row (greatest x.id) is `NULL`, therefore `(x.nr = y.nr) IS NOT TRUE` evaluates to TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get an id (add column, set column id = record number in database) use:

```
select a.*
  from the_table a
  left join the_table b on b.id = a.id + 1
                       and b.col1 = 0
 where a.col1 = 1
   and b.id is null
```

Comment: The `where` condition should be `where (a.col1 = 1 and b.id is null) or a.col1 = 0` - fluteflute wants to include 0s.

Answer (score 0):

USING a CTE to separate the lag-logic from the selection criteria.

```
DROP TABLE tmp.bits;
CREATE TABLE tmp.bits
    ( id SERIAL NOT NULL
    , bit INTEGER NOT NULL
    , code CHAR(1)
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.bits(bit, code) VALUES
(1, 'T' )
, (0, 'S' )
, (1, 'R' )
, (0, 'E' )
, (1, 'F' )
, (0, 'T' )
, (1, 'G' )
, (1, 'T' )
, (0, 'R' )
, (1, 'X' )
, (1, 'R' )
, (0, 'R' )
, (1, 'E' )
, (0, 'T' )
    ;

SET search_path='tmp';
SELECT * FROM bits;

-- EXPLAIN ANALYZE
WITH prevnext AS (
SELECT
    bt.id AS thisid
    , bt.bit  AS thisbit
    , bt.code AS thiscode
    , bp.bit AS prevbit
    , bp.code AS prevcode
    FROM bits bt
    LEFT JOIN bits bp ON (bt.id > bp.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM bits nx
        WHERE nx.id > bp.id
        AND nx.id < bt.id
        )   
    )
SELECT thisid, thisbit, thiscode
FROM prevnext
WHERE thisbit=0
OR prevbit IS NULL OR thisbit <> prevbit
    ;
```

EDIT:

for those poor soals that cannot use CTEs, it is easy to create a view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW prevnext AS (
SELECT
    bt.id AS thisid
    , bt.bit  AS thisbit
    ,bt.code AS thiscode
    , bp.bit AS prevbit
    , bp.code AS prevcode
    FROM bits bt
    LEFT JOIN bits bp ON (bt.id > bp.id)
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM bits nx
        WHERE nx.id > bp.id
        AND nx.id < bt.id
        )
    )
    ;
SELECT thisid, thisbit, thiscode
FROM prevnext
WHERE thisbit=0
OR prevbit IS NULL OR thisbit <> prevbit
    ;
```

Comment: Except that we are talking MySQL here. No CTE, no window functions.

Comment: I know, but the problem is very general (and tagged sql), besides: the CTE could always be wrapped into view.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select l.*
from logs l
where l.type = 0 or
      not (select type
           from (select * from logs order by `time` desc) n
           where n.machine = l.machine and
                 n.user = l.user and
                 n.time > l.time)
           group by () )
```